# PDFKit/Nodejs Annotations

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to use PDFKit from http://pdfkit.org/, my use case is little bit more advanced I want inject some javascript to PDF when the user clicks a link or button, I want to show popup widget with some information to select like drop down list. Also I'm looking for some text box, date annotations from server side. Is it possible to achieve with this library

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PDFKit is suitable for creating pdf files. Albeit the integration is a bit clunky, [pdf-annotate](https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js#readme) might be the solution for what you're looking.